# What does the Java Comparator.comparing() type signature mean?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I'm having trouble understanding the method signature:

```
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

Getting confused by `super`, `extends`, wild card (`?`) and multiple angle brackets. Please don't get me wrong, I understand basic generics. It is the higher constructs being used here which confuse me.

Comment: A simpler way using what I remember them... `? super T` => class T or its parent while `? extends U` => class U or its child

Comment: READ THE TUTORIAL! Study http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html .

Comment: Could you clarify: are you asking about `Compare.comparing()` *specifically*, or generic method signatures *in general*?

Comment: About this particular method signature. The method signature of Compare.comparing (not functionality). If you can explain what the return type, argument type etc. that would help;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the basic form of the function is

`static <T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<T, U> extractor)`

We'll deal with the finer-grained modifications later. What the above is saying is, in order:

- `static`: straightforward, importantly though, this means the function is not bound to the type of its object instance, so even though `Comparator` is defined and instantiated as `Comparator<T>` we still write `T` in...
- `<T, U>`: this tells us the function itself is generic over the types `T` and `U`. This is just like when you write `class <T, U> MyClass` - you're saying that these types will define the behavior of the rest of the function. In this case, these types define the parameters of the function, and will be *inferred* based on what parameter we provide. If we give a `Function<Foo,Bar>` to `comparing()` then the compiler will infer `T = Foo.class` and `U = Bar.class`.
- `Comparator<T>`: the return type, a thing capable of comparing `T`; fairly straightforward.
- `Function<T, U>`: a mapping from `T` to `U`; fairly straightforward.

Now for the rest:

- `<T, U>` is really `<T,U extends Comparable<? super U>>`, which means `T` is whatever and `U` needs to extend `Comparable` (i.e. be comparable) even if it's really just comparable based on its super type. For example, I may have `Bar extends Foo` where `Foo implements Comparable`; I can still compare objects of type `Bar` by treating them as `Foo`. Here's a concrete example:

  - Let's make a class, `MyBigInt implements Comparable<MyBigInt>`. Assume we've implemented the `Comparable` interface and our class is correctly compared based on its integer value.
  - Next let's make a new class `MyBigColorfulInt extends MyBigInt`, which adds some silly non-integer functionality - importantly, it does **not** implement `Comparable<MyBigColorfulInt>`, but as a subclass of `MyBigInt` it **does** (implicitly) implement `Comparable<MyBigInt>`.
  - Now, to bring it back to our problem with `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>`: say our type `T` contains within it a field of type `MyBigColorfulInt`, and I would like to *compare* objects of type `T` based on their `MyBigColorfulInt` member (this is `U`). **IF** the signature was `U extends Comparable<U>` we would be out of luck: `MyBigColorfulInt` does not implement `Comparable<MyBigColorfulInt>`. However, we really want to compare `MyBigColorfulInt`'s as `MyBigInt`'s, anyway. `U extends Comparable<? super U>>` lets us do this for free, because it lets `U` be compared based on its super class. If not for this, the best we could do is cast each `MyBigColorfulInt` to `MyBigInt` before comparing, which is not great.
- `Function<T, U>` is really `Function<? super T,? extends U>`, so one at a time:

  - `<? super T>` similar to the point above about `U`, all this really means is that we have to be able to extract something to compare (`U`) from `T`, and it's OK if the thing we're extracting really comes from `T`'s super class.
  - `<? extends U>` also similar (in a different way) to the point above: our function needs to extract a thing of type `U` to be compared, but it's alright if the thing we're extracting is a descendant of `U`, as long as it can be *used* as a `U` for the basis of our comparison.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort. Very nice explanation. Have one query:   In        U extends Comparable<? super U> - Why do we need <? super U> here [U or its parent]? What is its significance?

Comment: Updated my answer to give a detailed explanation :)

Comment: Great! Understood it now. Marking as answered. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Hi, your answer was great. However, I am struggling with two things, hope you can help me out: 
`U extends <? super U>` and `<? extends U>`. From your example, `U` is `MyBigColorfulInt`, so the first signature would be `MyBigColorfulInt extends <? super MyBigColorfulInt>`, which means "MyBigColorfulInt must implement the Comparable interface, directly or through a superclass". 
Now, the second signature would be `<? extends MyBigColorfulInt >` which means MyBigColorfulInt could be extracted or inflicted from one of its subclasses?

Comment: @DamianGDO your interpretations above are correct, but I'm not sure I understand what you're asking :)

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Oh no, I actually just wanted to see if I got the correct idea. Thank you for your respond.